# ajax response is 0 instead of 'script'

Tags: ajax

I keep getting a response of `0` instead of `string`, which is my function echoes. Why?

code from `functions.php`

```
// enque test.js
function add_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'test',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_localize_script('test', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_script' );

// ajax function
function my_AJAX_processing_function(){
   echo 'string';
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ACTION_NAME', 'my_AJAX_processing_function');
```

code from `test.js`

```
$(function () {

    var data = {
        action: 'ACTION_NAME'
    };

    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });

});
```

Comment: Is test.js properly included?  If it is try using jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... }); instead of the shorthand version at the top.

Comment: Please always [search the site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=ajax+response+0).

Comment: I think nopriv does not handle logged in users and this might be the case. in PHP you should add `add_action('wp_ajax_ACTION_NAME', 'my_AJAX_processing_function');`

Answer (score 2):

Ajax callbacks must always end with a die() to work correctly in WP.